# Write into excel sheet from dataset tables one by one

Tags: c#, excel, dataset

I have multiple tables in my dataset. I need to write all the datatables one by one into the excel and export the sheet in final step.

if the problem is already answered please post the link. because i could not find the relevant answers.

Comment: cs is never about finding the exact code to do what you want. Its about finding relevant pieces and forge them together. Just loop thru data table cell by cell and write them to corresponding cell in Excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you would have multiple data tables in C#, but ere is a simple example of how to save a data object to Excel.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection ;
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
                string sql = null;
                MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='c:\\csharp.net-informations.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
                MyConnection.Open();
                myCommand.Connection = MyConnection;
                sql = "Insert into [Sheet1$] (id,name) values('5','e')";
                myCommand.CommandText = sql;
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MyConnection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show (ex.ToString());
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a snippet of code I have written before that takes a C# Datatable Object and saves as a tab in an excel document.

You will have to install a NuGet for ClosedXML to have the functions available in the snippet.  Then reference that dll to use these functions.

```
 using ClosedXML.Excel;


 DataTable DT = MyDataTable;
 XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();
 IXLWorksheet UseLevelDataSheet= wb.Worksheets.Add(DT, "BootStrap Uselevel 
Data");
        IXLWorksheet MLE_EstimatesSheet= wb.Worksheets.Add(DT_estimates, "MLE estimates & CB_BCA");

        if (SavePath==null)
        {
            string DocFolder = 
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            string FileName = CreateFileName(DocFolder);
            wb.SaveAs(FileName);
            SavePath = FileName;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                wb.SaveAs(SavePath);
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                if (err.HResult== -2147024864)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Unable save, file is locked!");
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: I downvoted, because the error handling looks completely aweful to me.